# How to set properties and nested property's properties with expression

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I googled the propblem and also search the SO. There is a ton of solutions that all of them (that I found) are not completed. Can you help me please, to set a class's properties and its nested property's properties, choosen by a `lambda`, using `Reflection`?

```
public class Parent
{
    public class Child
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Number {get; private set; }
    public Child Nested { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        Nested = new Child();
    }

    public Test Set<TValue>(Expression<Func<???> func, TValue value)
    {
        // find the property name from expression
        // set the property by value
        return this;
    }
}
```

and in consumer, I want be able to:

```
Parent t = new Parent();
t.Set<int>(t => t.Number, 6)
 .set<string>(t => t.Name, "something")
 .Set<int>(t => t.Nested.Id, 25);
```

Comment: Why specifically expressions? Would `t.Set("Number", 6)` and `t.Set("Nested.Id", 25)` suffice? That is probably easier, and I can come up with some interesting ways to do that.

Comment: Its OK. I can find members name (by .(dot) between them). Can you suggest your solution please?

Comment: before I do... what is the reason you can't simply use direct C#? i.e. `t.Number = 6; t.Name = "something"; t.Nested.Id = 25;`

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually I'm new to C#. And I'm learning and learning and learning. It is right, that I can use `t.Name = ""`; But for big classes with many properties (and nested properties), it seems its not easy. So I think if I can use something like I told in Q, its more easier. Thanks in advance

Comment: why is that easier? why is that better? understanding what we are trying to *achieve* should always be paramount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent Set<TValue>(Expression<Func<Parent, TValue>> func, TValue value)
    {
        MemberExpression mex = func.Body as MemberExpression;
        if(mex == null) throw new ArgumentException();

        var pi = mex.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if(pi == null) throw new ArgumentException();

        object target = GetTarget(mex.Expression);
        pi.SetValue(target, value, null);
        return this;
    }

    private object GetTarget(Expression expr)
    {
        switch (expr.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Parameter:
                return this;
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                MemberExpression mex = (MemberExpression)expr;
                PropertyInfo pi = mex.Member as PropertyInfo;
                if(pi == null) throw new ArgumentException();
                object target = GetTarget(mex.Expression);
                return pi.GetValue(target, null);
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to set properties. not just the signature

Comment: thanks, and do this set nested properties values too? I'll test it

Comment: And... the `seeter`s are `private`. is this OK?

Comment: @king.net - Yes it works for nested properties, and should work with private setters.